# Write a programme to input 10 numbers from the user and print greatest of all

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, max, undefined-behavior

I have written the programme and there's some kind of coding mistake I guess.
The inputting part in working properly but finding and printing greatest number isn't.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    int i, arr[10],c=0;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        printf("enter 10 nos. for arr[%d] :",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        while(arr[i]>c)
        {
            c=arr[i];
        }
        printf("Greatest number in a given array is:%d",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are out of bounds on arr when  i == 10,arrays are 0 based. Iterate from 0 to  i < 10. Also if statement is better than while for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array declared like

```
int a[N];
```

where N is some positive integer value then the valid range of indices to access elements of the array is `[0, N)`.

It means that for example this for loop

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    printf("enter 10 nos. for arr[%d] :",i);
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

must look like

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    printf("enter 10 nos. for arr[%d] :",i);
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
```

This while loop

```
    while(arr[i]>c)
    {
        c=arr[i];
    }
```

just does not make a sense and can be an infinite loop.

Moreover this call of printf

```
    printf("Greatest number in a given array is:%d",c);
```

is placed within a for loop.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int arr[N];

    printf( "Enter %d numbers:\n", N );
 
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf("\t%d: ", i + 1 );
        scanf( "%d", arr + i );
    }

    int max = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( arr[max] < arr[i] ) max = i;
    }

    printf( "The greatest number in the given array is: %d\n", arr[max] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this particular case the `while` loop cannot be infinite, but I agree that it is not the right way to write it

Answer (score 2):

In C indexes start from 0, so `for(i=1;i<=10;i++)` condition is wrong in two ways: you're starting from the second array item (missing `arr[0]`), then you're going out of bounds with `arr[i]` when `i` is 10.

You should change the `while` to `if` as well, since you don't actually intend to have a loop there. You only need to execute the code under the condition once. You should also consider what happens when you have negative values in your input.

Last but not least - the `printf` probably should be outside the `for` loop if you want to print out the end result.

Answer (score 0):

First, index of array starts with zero and arr[10] is out of bound.
Second, assign the minimum integer value to c.
Third, change while to if and put the second printf() out of second for statement.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main() {
    // Taking Variables
    int a[10];
    int i;
    int greatest;

    //Taking exactly 10 inputs in an array by using for loop
    printf("Enter ten values:");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    //Iterating through the array and comparing all the values, the one which is the greatest of all is printed
    greatest = a[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      if (a[i] > greatest){
        greatest = a[i];}
      }
    printf("Greatest of ten numbers is %d", greatest);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please at least indent the code properly. And some explanation would also be a good idea.

Comment: good that you initialized c with a[0] instead of 0  for negative numbers

Comment: I don't believe just providing the code is helpful much in the long term. So you solved the problem, kudos, but will that help the OP solve the next one?

Comment: After your edit, it's worse. It's not only less readable than before, but the indentation is still wrong. And the comments you added are not really helpful.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Oops.. Now I have explained and fixed everything